# Implementing Store instruction using inline assembly in RISC-V

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I'm quite new to inline assembly, so I need your help to be sure that I use it correctly. I need to add assembly code inside my C code that is compiled with the Risc-v toolchain.

The instruction that we will be focusing on is ADDI - I want to store a certain value to a specific register. As shown on page 116 of RISCV-ISA-Specification, the instruction format is as follows:

```
imm[11:0] | rs1 | 000 | rd | 0010011 |  ADDI
```

Like I read, i can use the register x0 as hardwire zero to directly store the imm value to the register rd (i choose one of the function registers). If I per example the value 15 to store, this would be:

- rs1: zero register (register x0, i.e. 0b00000)
- rd: a0 register    (register x10, i.e. 0b01010)
- 15:                (i.e. 0b1111 - extended to 0b000000001111)

Hence, by filling in the corresponding register bits of the original instruction, we have the following:

```
000000001111 | 00000| 000 | 01010| 0010011 |  ADDI
```

and by the 2-byte wall:

```
0000 0000 |1111 0000 | 00000101 | 0001 0011 
->   0x00       0xF0       0x05        0x13
```

Since RISC-V uses little endian, the corresponding inline assembly can be generated by:

```
__asm__ volatile(".byte 0x13, 0x05, 0xF0, 0x00");
```

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Yes your encoding is correct. You can verify with a disassembler. It is bad use of inline asm, but I assume you know that and are forced to do it this way.

Comment: That inline asm would only be safe inside a `__attribute__((naked))` function or at global scope; otherwise it's necessary to tell the compiler about the operands (including the memory being stored to).  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Comment: If you need to manually encode an instruction with your opcode but the compiler's choice of registers, I think there's a `.inst` which take an opcode and list of registers or something like that.  That's normally better (and more maintainable) than emitting raw machine code with `.byte`.

Comment: U are right, if I am inserting my instruction into my c-code, I am getting a SIGSEGV error: 
"A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed"