# Signal SIGSEGV when using RISCV assembly inline Code in the c-File

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I have been working with the RISCV ISA over the weekend. The command

```
00000011 | 00000| 000 | 01010| 0010011 | ADDI
```

(RISCV-ISA-Specification page 116) should assign the value 15 to the a0- register.

I add the command as

```
__asm__ volatile(".byte 0x13, 0x05, 0xF0, 0x00");
```

(little endian already considered) in my c-file in the main, it compiles, but at (gbd) run I get a SIGSEV Error

As I could read, the error is related to an invalid memory address.

*A Segmentation Fault occurs when a program tries to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or when it tries to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, when it tries to write to a read-only memory location or to overwrite part of the operating system).
On Unix-like operating systems, a signal called SIGSEGV is sent to a process accessing an invalid memory address.*

The error occurs only with the command. Similar commands like LW are failing, too

Comment: try to disassemble your code and see what instruction it sees.

Comment: The encoding looks correct for RV64.  Are you perhaps compiling for RV32?  Can you post a [mcve] that is a complete program?  Perhaps your code is placed in a non-executable page.

Comment: I agree that the encoding looks right. There's no way an `addi` can seg fault.  Problem is elsewhere.  Look at the faulting instruction address and view the disassembly in the debugger.

Comment: Like we [commented on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355694/implementing-store-instruction-using-inline-assembly-in-risc-v#comment132966906_75355694), this inline asm isn't safe inside a normal function because you aren't telling the compiler about registers you modify.  This instruction itself won't segfault if it only modifies registers, but it's totally normal for later compiler-generated code to fault after you step on its registers.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended .  And use a debugger to find the fault.